# How I can map this three class into Realm?

Tags: android, json, realm

I have 3 (POJO) classes which I have requested from NewsApi by Retrofit. I should take this class and make a RealmObject. How can I do it?
Here this classes :

```
public class Source {
    @SerializedName("id") @Expose private Object id;
    @SerializedName("name") @Expose private String name;
    public Object getId() { return id;}
    public void setId(Object id) {  this.id = id;}
    public String getName() {   return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {  this.name = name;}
}
```

Second class :

```
public class Article {

    @SerializedName("source") @Expose private Source source;
    @SerializedName("author") @Expose private String author;
    @SerializedName("title") @Expose private String title;
    @SerializedName("description") @Expose private String description;
    @SerializedName("url") @Expose private String url;
    @SerializedName("urlToImage") @Expose private String urlToImage;
    @SerializedName("publishedAt") @Expose private String publishedAt;

    public Source getSource() {return source;}

    public void setSource(Source source) {  this.source = source;}

    public String getAuthor() { return author;}

    public void setAuthor(String author) {  this.author = author;}

    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getDescription() {return description;}

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;}

    public String getUrl() {    return url;}

    public void setUrl(String url){this.url = url;}

    public String getUrlToImage() {return urlToImage;}

    public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;}

    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }
}
```

Third class

```
public class ArticlesResponse {

    @SerializedName("status") private String status;
    @SerializedName("sortBy") private String sortBy;
    @SerializedName("source") private String source;
    @SerializedName("articles") private List<Article> articles;

    public ArticlesResponse() {}

    public String getStatus() {return status;}

    public void setStatus(String status) {  this.status = status;}

    public String getSortBy() { return sortBy;}

    public void setSortBy(String sortBy) {this.sortBy = sortBy;}

    public String getSource() { return source;}

    public void setSource(String source) {  this.source = source;}

    public List<Article> getArticles() {    return articles;}

    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {this.articles = articles;}

    public ArticlesResponse getArticleResponse() {  return null;}
}
```

I thought that I should make three classes which would extentnds RealmObject.

```
class Source : extends RealmObject {}
class Article : extends RealmObject {and here RealmList<Source> }
class ArticleResponse : extends RealmObject {and here RealmList<Article>}
```

but what about fields which are Objects?

```
private Object id;
```

Comment: The fields which are objects need to have associated realm objects all the way down until you hit primitive types.

Comment: Well what is `Object`? That is not exactly specific at all.

Comment: Realm supports boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double, String, Date and byte[] field types. (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types) Whatever this `Object` of your is, you need "encapsulate" with another RealmObject.

Comment: Or just map it to a String